# Как подтянуть qml зависимости с помощью windeployqt?

Tags: qml

Проект написан на С++ с помощью Qt. ГУИ работает с помощью qml. Если натравить windeployqt на готовый ехе, то все необходимые Qt библиотеки подтягиваются без проблем, но qml подтягивать не хочет (QtQml, QtQuick и тд...). Приходится перебором определять какие библиотеки нужны. Depency Walker так же не может показать эти зависимости. Я не первый в проекте кто занимается этим вопросом. Где-то я слышал что хитрость состоит в том, что qml зависимости линкуются каким-то своим магическим способом. Может утилиты какие-то есть?

Comment: У windeployqt есть параметр --qmldir. В этот параметр передаётся путь к вашей папке с qml формами.

Comment: Пробовали. Результат абсолютно такой же. Мне надо хотя бы увидеть эти зависимости чтобы добавить библиотеки в скрипт для NSIS, который используется на билдсервере.

Comment: windeployqt - а есть такое для линукса?)